# Displaying a Remote Page on a website, PHP or ModRewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, file-get-contents

My client has a family of websites, each different domains and different contents, 5 websites showing very similar content angled for the 5 different locations.

Most of the information content (*not* the CSS files, layout,- but all the paragraph texts and images) is in the database. The www.core.com site is the site that my clients customers log in to to update their content pages.

The current way this system works is that each website has a set of static content pages that draws the data from the database. My clients plan is to have a central core website page (www.core.com/BusinessPage) that draws the content from the database in a CMS-type system and wraps it in (neutral) HTML tags and then he wants this content to be distributed to the five "satellite" sites.

Aside from this content, the 5 sites all have their own unique layouts, CSS and HTML. *(as an aside: 4 of the sites are HTML4 and one is HTML5)*. These Business pages are not expected to follow the theme of the location websites but are a generally neutral design.

So, what is the best way of producing the content from the site www.core.com/page?id=1234 and then having this displayed on the other sites such as www.locationsite1.co.uk/businessName/index.php ?

**My thoughts so far on possible approaches:**

> 1) Use PHP file_get_contents in each
>   www.locationsite1.co.uk/BusinessName/index.php  to open and run the page on
>   the core site
>   and then output that whole page on each location site. I have very
>   little experience with file_get_contents grabbing data from other
>   domains.
>
> 2) Use a ModRewrite for each location site to have the URL display
>   www.locationsite1.co.uk/businessName but the content to be
>   www.core.com/page?id=1234 . I have some experience of modRewrite and
>   this seems the likely way to go at the moment. However I'm not quite 
>   convinced (hence this question).
>
> 3) iframe HTML grab-and-display mechanic.
>
> 4) Using PHP include to call the page as an include (I think this
>   could only work if all file calls to CSS,JS files etc. are absolute,
>   but that's totally possible) .

Which of my approaches, if any, are the best way of doing these things? Is there another approach that I have not thought of?

Cheers

Comment: Erm... thought about heavy client? Have PHP scripts fetch from the database and return XML or JSON and have a JavaScript client XHR (AJAX) the PHP scripts then throw the information on the DOM

Comment: I don't know what Heavy client is, I will Google.... it seems a different approach to what I'm used to, with the Javascript aspect!

Comment: I'd say to take a look at AngularJS (https://angularjs.org/), it's an approach called Model View Controller. It's a very different way of thinking - but it's amazingly powerful. I'd check out the tutorials on the website to start, the way I learned is from a book that teaches the MEAN (MongoDB, ExpressJS, Angular, Node.JS) stack, but since you use PHP that probably isn't that useful. However, if you want to take a look, here's a link: http://www.amazon.com/Write-Modern-Apps-MEAN-Stack/dp/0133930157

Comment: Cheers, I'm aware of MVC methodology with Magento etc. But I'm not sure how to apply that in this case, where I'm looking at the best way to emulate one web domains contents on other web domains.